# Android - How to create CheckBox drawable?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-drawable

When using `CheckBox`, some Drawable for this "check" icon is created - `AnimatedStateListDrawable`. Is there any way to create this drawable programmatically without `CheckBox`? The only thing I've found inside `CompoundButton` class is this resource - `com.android.internal.R.styleable.CompoundButton_button`.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:

```
val attrs = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple)
val ta = getContext().theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)
ta.getDrawable(0)
```

For RadioButton it's `android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle`.